# How does the below C macro example compile?

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor

The code below does not give the correct output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 22/7
#define AREA(r)  PI * r * r
int main() {
    printf("Pi: %d\n", PI);
    printf("Area: %d\n", AREA(8));
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas the code below gives the correct (nearest) output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 22/7
#define AREA(r)  r * r * PI
int main() {
    printf("Pi: %d\n", PI);
    printf("Area: %d\n", AREA(8));
    return 0;
}
```

How exactly do these code differ?

Why is it so? I am not able to understand the difference between how both the above codes would give different answers.

Comment: What's the correct output supposed to be?

Comment: Please [edit] and show the expected and actual output for the two pieces of code.

Comment: For even more fun, try `AREA(4+2)`.  Where did these macros come from?

Comment: Is it just me or is 22/7 = 3.14286 whereas PI is 3.14159. Where does this 22/7 come from? Who told you to use it?

Comment: @Lundin I think they used this approximation in the middle ages.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Umm ok. Yeah apparently Archimedes made the same remark as I did some 250 years BC... So why insist on using this form some >two thousand years later?

Comment: One more point: This illustrates why, in general, one shouldn't use function-like macros like `#define AREA(r) r * r * PI` in the first place.  Even after adding the necessary parentheses, such a macro can still have problems.  Using an ordinary function, however, will work naturally and properly the first time.

Comment: For the record (Lundin, Jabberwocky): 22/7 is a well-known approximation of π, known since antiquity and still commonly used today.  It's actually a bit more accurate than the (also well-known and popular) approximation 3.14.  Why would someone use it?  Because it's accurate enough for many purposes, and easy to remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your `PI` macro:

```
#define PI 22/7
```

There are two problems with this:  (1)  It's not wrapped in parentheses, to guard it against parts of it binding more tightly to other parts of the expression in which it's expanded, and (2) It's doing integer division.

If you have `22/7` by itself, it's just `3`.  Presumably that's not what you want.  But the `AREA` macro, which also has problems, looks like this:

```
#define AREA(r)  r * r * PI
```

With `PI` expanded, this is equivalent to:

```
#define AREA(r)  r * r * 22/7
```

Assuming `r` is a simple variable or constant, this is equivalent to:

```
#define AREA(r)  (r * r * 22) / 7
```

If `r` is an integer, it's still doing integer division, but it's only truncating at the end, so the result will be more accurate.

Note that `AREA` has two problems of its own:  (1) It's not wrapping its argument, `r`, in parentheses, and (2) It's not wrapping the expression as a whole in parentheses.

For problem (1), imagine passing something like `2+3` as `r`.  Since multiplication associates more tightly than addition, this clearly won't do what you want.

If you want an accurate result, you would normally use an accurate floating-point value for pi, rather than the extremely inaccurate approximation 22/7.  But if you do want to use 22/7, you should still use a floating point value for it:

```
#define PI (22.0/7.0)
```

Then you can fix `AREA`:

```
#define AREA(r)  (PI * (r) * (r))
```

This will properly protect the arguments and final results from reassociating after expansion, but note that the result will have type `double`.  Also note that its argument, `r`, is evaluated twice.

But a better approximation to pi is preferable.  On Linux, `math.h` exports `M_PI`, which is far more accurate.

Comment: Good answer, but I cannot agree that 0.04% is "extremely inaccurate". :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit My point is that it's only using a small fraction of the available precision in a double.

Answer (score 3):

Try expanding the macro. The first one is 22 / 7 * 8 * 8. All values are integers, so you get rounding errors and the calculation is basically 3 * 8 * 8 = 192.

The second expression is 8 * 8 * 22 / 7. So the calculation is 1408 / 7 = 201.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplication and division is done from left to right.
So, AREA(8) in the first example expands to
22/7 * 8 * 8 which is evaluated like so:
(((22/7) * 8) * 8), i.e 3 * 8 * 8 = 192.

The other variant gives:
(((8*8)*22)/7) = (64 * 22)/7 = 1408/7 = 201.

If you want better precision, use floating point, i.e.
#define PI (22.0/7.0)
or, why not use a better approximation of pi:
#define PI (3.141593)

But then you should use %f in printf. (as commented by Jabberwocky)

Comment: ... and `%d` needs to be changed to `%f` in the `printf`s if fp is involved.

Comment: 22 / 7.0 would also work.