# Trying to find a way to write this "#define G 6.67 * pow(10, -11)" line in a way that will work without using "pow" IN C

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define constants
#define G 6.67 * pow(10, -11)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

I tried using pow but that doesn't work when using #define.

Comment: Re “I tried using pow but that doesn't work when using #define”: `#define` directives and macro replacement do not care whether you use `pow`. It is where you use the macro that is an issue.

Comment: See also hints at [How does the below C macro example compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75158020)

Answer (score 4):

Just write it in scientific notation.  See [§6.4.4.2 Floating constants](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.2) of the C standard.

```
#define G 6.67e-11
```